# custom adapter with notifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: android

I follow example from here using section listview
http://lalit3686.blogspot.com/2012/05/sectionadapter.html

But how can I implement `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Adding listener to update the listview data:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(SectionAdapterActivity.this, ""+position+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            test();

        }
    });
```

I'm adding new function only for change/update value (testing only):

```
public void test()
{
    hashMap.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        hashMap.put("Mail", String.valueOf(1100 + i), 1);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        hashMap.put("Case", String.valueOf(2100 + j), 15);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        hashMap.put("File", String.valueOf(10000 + j), 20);
    }

    mListView.invalidate();
    mListView.invalidateViews();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

    Log.e("dada", hashMap.toString());
}}
```

Seems like does not work, can anyone help?

Comment: I am not very sure about this but call NotifyDataSetChanged() first and then try invalidateViews().

Comment: Post the adapter and the code rows where you declare it

Comment: is Toast is visible ? and list get blank or nothing happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve with calling notifyDataSetChange().

this method is taking affect only when you change the logic data collection / database which been used by the adapter, after it has created already. in this situation - it would cause to update of the list with the new data

if that's what you want to do, then to use it - what you need to do is simple:  just call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and that's it :).  nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make Sure that you have used the Same `hashmap` and `adapter` objects for the `ListView` and that `hashmap` object is used when creating the `adapter` object.
2. Make sure the `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` is been called, **put some log there**.
3. *Print the HashMap object values in Log after calling notifyDatasetChanged() and check the items in ListView and in Log are same or not*.
4. The effect of `notifyDatasetChanged()` can be shown *only if the data in HashMap get changed* if it's remain as prev then you can not determine as it has been called or not.
5. Looking at your code, I suppose that *there is no problem in this part of code*.